# how can I share an asp.net session between http and https

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-6, https

I read that a page which runs under an https connection cannot share an InProc Session (based on cookies) with another page (or the same for that matter) running under regular http. My site is running on Server 2003, IIS 6 and .Net 2.0.

After some experiments it appears that a page which stores data in session while being connected through https CAN subsequently access the data even if running under plain http.

So, is it possible or should I go over and look for flaws in the SSL configuration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302426.aspx):

> When a user moves back and forth
>   between secure and public areas, the
>   ASP.NET-generated session cookie (or
>   URL if you have enabled cookie-less
>   session state) moves with them in
>   plaintext, but the authentication
>   cookie is never passed over
>   unencrypted HTTP connections *as long
>   as the Secure cookie property is set*.

So basically, the cookie can be passed over both HTTP and HTTPS if the `Secure` property is set to `false`.

I have avoided this issue by adding this to my `Global.asax` file:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.IsSecureConnection) Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = false;
}
```

This means that if the Session cookie is created over HTTP, it will only be accessible over HTTPS.

Comment: What are the safety implications of turning this off?

Answer (score 6):

*IIS setting
In the IIS properties window, under the ASP tab –> Session Properties, there is a setting for “New ID on Secure Connections”*

I fixed this intermittent issue for myself by setting this to false.

Comment: This appears to be gone in IIS7 - or perhaps I'm just not clear on where this would be found. Is this per site or global to the server?

Comment: @chris-moschini In IIS 7 there's a 'Session State' icon under 'ASP.NET', so if that's where you're looking, you're in the right place -- and yes, you are correct; that setting is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for the problem doesn't turn up much chatter about it so far, still looking.

*Edit*: okay finding some stuff now.

Right it seems that it will work fine if both sets of pages are in the same application/website.

So I'd go ahead and carry on, feeling reassured.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above solution does not work try this. I have cracked this out after doing research of a couple of days.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    ...
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never
});
```