# how to keep session id http to https in .Net

Tags: .net, iis-7, sessionid

My session id changes when I call a https page from http page. How to keep it between them? 
NOTE: My server is on a hosting company so I can not make a setting on server or IIS. I checked and did the answer on [how can I share an asp.net session between http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567535/how-can-i-share-an-asp-net-session-between-http-and-https)  but the same result.

Comment: Check out the answers to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567535/how-can-i-share-an-asp-net-session-between-http-and-https

Comment: I did it but the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with Cookies. I write my datas to cookie files and read them from cookies.